# What cases do the GHC occurs check identify?

Tags: haskell, ghc, typechecking

The GHC occurs check prevents you from constructing infinite types. Is its purpose to prevent common errors in code or to prevent the typechecker from looping indefinitely, or both?

What cases does it identify and is it possible for a malicious user to trick it (as in a Safe Haskell context) into looping? If the type system is Turing-complete (is it?) I don't understand how GHC can guarantee that the computation will halt.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Think of type inference as solving a system of equations. Let's look at an
example:

```
f x = (x,2)
```

How can we deduce the type of `f`? We see that it is a function:

```
f :: a -> b
```

Additionally, from the structure of `f` we can see that the following
equations hold simulatenously:

```
b = (c,d)
d = Int
c = a
```

By solving this system of equations we can see that the type of `f` is `a -> (a,
Int)`. Now let's look at the following (erroneous) function:

```
f x = x : x
```

The type of `(:)` is `a -> [a] -> [a]`, so this generates the following system of
equations (simplified):

```
a = a
a = [a]
```

So we get an equation `a = [a]`, from which we can conclude that this system of equations doesn't have a solution, and therefore the code is not well-typed. If we didn't reject the equation `a = [a]`, we would indeed go in an infinite loop adding equations `a = [a]`, `a = [[a]]`, `a = [[[a]]]`, etc to our system (alternatively, as Daniel notes in his answer, we could allow infinite types in our type system, but that would make erroneous programs such as `f x = x : x` to typecheck).

You can also test this in ghci:

```
> let f x = x : x

<interactive>:2:15:
    Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a0 = [a0]
    In the second argument of `(:)', namely `x'
    In the expression: x : x
    In an equation for `f': f x = x : x
```

As to your other questions: GHC Haskell's type system is not Turing-complete and the typechecker is guaranteed to halt - unless you enable [`UndecidableInstances`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.2/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#undecidable-instances), in which case it theoretically can go in an infinite loop. GHC, however, ensures termination by having a fixed-depth recursion stack, <s>so it's not possible to construct a program on which it never halts</s> (**edit:** according to C.A.McCann's comment, it is possible after all - there's an analogue of tail recursion on the type level that allows to loop without increasing the stack depth).

It is, however, possible to make compilation take arbitrarily long time, since the complexity of Hindley-Milner type inference is exponential in the worst (but not the average!) case:

```
dup x = (x,x)

bad = dup . dup . dup . dup . dup . dup . dup . dup
      . dup . dup . dup . dup . dup . dup . dup . dup
      . dup . dup . dup . dup . dup . dup . dup . dup
      . dup . dup . dup . dup . dup . dup . dup . dup
```

Safe Haskell won't protect you from this - take a look at [mueval](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mueval) if you want to allow potentially malicious users compile Haskell programs on your system.

Comment: It's entirely possible to hang GHC via `UndecidableInstances`. I don't recall the exact details, but you can loop without increasing the stack depth using something that amounts to tail recursion.

Comment: @C.A.McCann Would be interesting to see an example. I just quoted the manual.

Comment: Don't have an example on hand right now, but I'll dig one up for you tonight. I do recall it being very hard to do *unintentionally*.

Comment: Actually, here's [an old hpaste](http://hpaste.org/49196) that I'm pretty sure caused whatever version of GHC I had at the time to hang, but I can't test it right now. Note the obvious layer of indirection, as alternately constructs and then evaluates expressions rather than using a single recursive type instance.

Comment: @C.A.McCann Thanks. I tried that with GHC 7.4.1 - it typechecks fine, but evaluating `bar` in GHCi never finishes.

Comment: I seem to recall it hanging when I simply loaded the file before, but yeah, GHC won't necessarily jump down the rabbit hole unless you ask it to type-check something that lures it in. For instance, I think putting `undefined` as the value of `bar` instead of `()` made a difference when I wrote it.

Comment: @C.A.McCann Changing `()` to `undefined` makes no difference with my version of GHC.

Answer (score 8):

> The GHC occurs check prevents you from constructing infinite types.

This is true only in the very literal sense of preventing types that are *syntactically* infinite. What's really going on here is just a *recursive* type where the unification algorithm would need to, in a sense, inline the recursion.

It's always possible to define exactly the same type by making the recursion explicit. This can even be done generically, using a type-level version of `fix`:

```
newtype Fix f = Fix (f (Fix f))
```

As an example, the type `Fix ((->) a)` is equivalent to unifying `b` with `(a -> b)`.

In practice, however, "infinite type" errors almost always indicate an error in the code (so if it's broke, you probably shouldn't `Fix` it). The usual scenario is mixing up argument order or otherwise having an expression in the wrong place in code that doesn't use explicit type signatures.

A type inference system that was extremely naive in the right way could potentially expand the recursion until it ran out of memory, but the halting problem doesn't enter into it--if a type needs to unify with part of itself, that's never going to work (at least in Haskell, there may be languages that instead treat it as equivalent to the explicitly recursive `newtype` above).

Neither type checking nor type inference in GHC are Turing-complete unless you enable `UndecidableInstances`, in which case you can do arbitrary computation via functional dependencies or type families.

Safe Haskell doesn't really enter the picture at all. It's easy to generate very large inferred types that will exhaust system memory despite being finite, and if memory serves me Safe Haskell doesn't restrict use of `UndecidableInstances` anyway.

Answer (score 7):

I have the following wonderful mail in my bookmarks: [There's nothing wrong with infinite types!](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.cafe/17105) Even with infinite types, there's no real danger of making the typechecker loop. The type system is not Turing complete (unless you explicitly ask for it to be with something like the `UndecidableInstances` extension).

Answer (score 4):

The purpose (in Haskell compilers) is to prevent common errors in code.  It is possible to construct a type checker and inference engine which would support infinite recursion of types.  There is some further information in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963376/why-dont-type-synonyms-permit-recursion-in-haskell).

OCaml implements recursive types with `-rectypes`, so it's definitely possible.  The OCaml community will be much more versed in some of the problems that arise (the behavior is off by default).

The occurs check identifies infinite type expansions.  For example, this code:

```
Prelude> let a = [a]
<interactive>:2:10:
    Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t0 = [t0]
    In the expression: a
    In the expression: [a]
    In an equation for `a': a = [a]
```

if you try to work out the type by hand, the type is `[ [ [ [ ... ] ] ] ]`.  It's impossible to write such types by hand, because they're infinite.

The occurs check occurs during type inferencing, which is a separate stage from type checking.  Infinite types would have to be inferred, because they can't be annotated manually.  Haskell-98 type inference is [decidable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decidability_%28logic%29), so it's impossible to trick the compiler into looping (barring bugs of course, which I suspect [this example](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7197/crash-your-favorite-compiler) exploits).  GHC by default uses a restricted subset of System F for which type inference is also decidable.  With some extensions, such as `RankNTypes`, GHC does allow code for which type inference is undecidable, but then requires a type annotation, so again there is no danger of the type inference stage looping.

Since Turing complete languages are undecidable, the default type system cannot be Turing-complete.  I don't know if GHC's type system becomes Turing-complete with some combination of extensions enabled, but certain extensions (e.g. `UndecidableInstances`) allow writing code that will crash the compiler with a stack overflow.

Incidentally, the main problem with disabling the occurs check is that many common coding mistakes result in infinite type errors, so disabling it usually leads to more problems than it solves.  If you do intend to use an infinite type, a newtype wrapper will allow it without much excess notation.

Comment: The example you link to is a long-standing bug that has nothing to do with type inference/checking--it's the optimizer getting confused by a (valid, but weird) recursive type and basically trying to unroll and inline an infinite loop, which does not work very well. :] If memory serves me it'd be tricky to fix without losing valid optimizations, and only happens in very contrived examples.

Comment: Oh, and as for being Turing-complete: See [this hpaste](http://hpaste.org/49196) I unearthed in response to another answer.