# Up-to-date Prolog implementation benchmarks?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, gnu-prolog

Are there any up-to-date Prolog implementation benchmarks (with results)?

I found [this](https://www.mercurylang.org/about/bench/ratios.html) on the [mercury](/questions/tagged/mercury) web site. Surprisingly, it shows a 20-fold gap between [swi-prolog](/questions/tagged/swi-prolog) and Aquarius. I suspect that these results are pretty old. Does this gap still hold? Personally, I'd also like to see some comparisons with the occurs check turned on, since it has a major impact on performance, and some compilers might be better than others at optimizing it away.

Of the more recent comparisons, I found [this](http://www.david-reitter.com/compling/prolog/compare.html) claim that [gnu-prolog](/questions/tagged/gnu-prolog) is 2x faster than SWI, and YAP is 4x faster than SWI on one specific code base.

---

Edit:

> a specific case where the occurs check is needed for a real world problem

Sure: [type inference in Haskell, OCaml, Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493773/) or theorem provers such as [this one](http://www.ai.sri.com/%7Estickel/pttp.html). I also think the burden is on the programmer to prove that his code doesn't need the occurs check. [Tests can only prove that you do need it, not that you don't need it](https://ronjeffries.com/xprog/articles/qa/xp_q_and_a_absence/).

Comment: Side note: of all the Java-based Prolog systems [listed on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Prolog_implementations), none are "compilers". This seems strange, since a Prolog->WAM compiler is about 3-5 KLOC, as I understand it, so it's not exceedingly complex.

Comment: Based on the documentation (https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(2,%271.3%27,swi(%27/doc/Manual/swiorother.html%27)) ), SWI prolog was not really designed for absolute top performance. It is mainly for extra features (and research).

Comment: But how much "fast" do you need? As usual for "benchmarks" and even more for Prolog, it is best to have your specific problem programmed out before you run comparisons on the hardware that interests you (ARM anyone?)

Comment: @DavidTonhofer If you look at the results, they are fairly consistent across 10 different tasks: *e.g.* nuProlog is only 2x faster than SWI, but interestingly there is not a single problem where it is slower.

Comment: @MaxB The JVM is not an ideal target for a WAM or a WAM-like implementation. The WAM is a brilliant design with careful thought about performance (remember, it was invented when computers had a tiny fraction of today's memory/processing speed) and thus better materialized in lower level programming languages like C.

Comment: I gave this a close vote because I don't feel it is a useful question. In my many years of using Prolog I have never had a problem with `occurs check` not being active. If you can show a specific case where the `occurs check` is needed for a real world problem you need then I would reconsider. I do like many of your questions but this one could lead others to believe that the `occurs check` is always needed.

Comment: I do like many of your questions but I feel this one should be deleted. If if gave some real code and asked how it could be improved at code review then it would make more sense.

Comment: @PauloMoura Is there a particular WAM instruction that's hard to execute on, or compile to JVM? As I understand it, WAM requires garbage collection, which JVM already has.

Comment: @MaxB No as much WAM instructions but WAM memory organization, which allows a number of clever optimizations. See https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220986765_Warren's_Abstract_Machine_A_Tutorial_Reconstruction

Comment: @MaxB The Oracle JVM does not do tail-call optimization, for one (unless that changed in the meantime, but I don't think so). Being business-oriented, C-tradition-oriented, the designers must have thought "rare are those that do (or understand) recursion anway"

Comment: @DavidTonhofer There are languages that compile to JVM and have tail-recursion optimization: Kotlin and Clojure (*mutual* tail-recursion can be problematic in them)

Comment: @MaxB Sadly, they don't. That's why in Clojure for example, you do not do vanilla recursive calls, but you use "loop constructs" to tell the compiler to generate a loop: [recur](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/recur). Of course, one is not necessarily worse off with that.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer `recur` is just a syntactic choice (something about being more explicit) In Kotlin or Kawa a function just refers to itself. [The difficulties of proper tail call optimization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/157684) didn't stop the users of Clojure, BTW.

Comment: Of interest: [Performance SWI-Prolog 8.3.5 vs YAP 6.5.0](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/performance-swi-prolog-8-3-5-vs-yap-6-5-0/2779) - I still am not fond of the question, but also believe you should have any valid info so that you can decide for yourself. There are more such post at the [SWI-Prolog forum](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's also a classical set of Prolog benchmarks that can be used for comparing Prolog implementations. Some Prolog systems include them (e.g. SWI-Prolog). They are also included in the Logtalk distribution, which allows running them with the supported backends:

https://github.com/LogtalkDotOrg/logtalk3/tree/master/examples/bench

In the current Logtalk git version, you can start it with the backend you want to benchmark and use the queries:

```
?- {bench(loader)}.
...
?- run.
```

These will run each benchmark 1000 times are reported the total time. Use `run/1` for a different number of repetitions. For example, in my macOS system using SWI-Prolog 8.3.15 I get:

```
?- run.
boyer: 20.897818 seconds
chat_parser: 7.962188999999999 seconds
crypt: 0.14653999999999812 seconds
derive: 0.004462999999997663 seconds
divide10: 0.002300000000001745 seconds
log10: 0.0011489999999980682 seconds
meta_qsort: 0.2729539999999986 seconds
mu: 0.04534600000000211 seconds
nreverse: 0.016964000000001533 seconds
ops8: 0.0016230000000021505 seconds
poly_10: 1.9540520000000008 seconds
prover: 0.05286200000000463 seconds
qsort: 0.030829000000004214 seconds
queens_8: 2.2245050000000077 seconds
query: 0.11675499999999772 seconds
reducer: 0.00044199999999960937 seconds
sendmore: 3.048624999999994 seconds
serialise: 0.0003770000000073992 seconds
simple_analyzer: 0.8428750000000065 seconds
tak: 5.495768999999996 seconds
times10: 0.0019139999999993051 seconds
unify: 0.11229400000000567 seconds
zebra: 1.595203000000005 seconds
browse: 31.000829000000003 seconds
fast_mu: 0.04102400000000728 seconds
flatten: 0.028527999999994336 seconds
nand: 0.9632950000000022 seconds
perfect: 0.36678499999999303 seconds
true.
```

For SICStus Prolog 4.6.0 I get:

```
| ?- run.
boyer: 3.638 seconds
chat_parser: 0.7650000000000006 seconds
crypt: 0.029000000000000803 seconds
derive: 0.0009999999999994458 seconds
divide10: 0.001000000000000334 seconds
log10: 0.0009999999999994458 seconds
meta_qsort: 0.025000000000000355 seconds
mu: 0.004999999999999893 seconds
nreverse: 0.0019999999999997797 seconds
ops8: 0.001000000000000334 seconds
poly_10: 0.20500000000000007 seconds
prover: 0.005999999999999339 seconds
qsort: 0.0030000000000001137 seconds
queens_8: 0.2549999999999999 seconds
query: 0.024999999999999467 seconds
reducer: 0.001000000000000334 seconds
sendmore: 0.6079999999999997 seconds
serialise: 0.0019999999999997797 seconds
simple_analyzer: 0.09299999999999997 seconds
tak: 0.5869999999999997 seconds
times10: 0.001000000000000334 seconds
unify: 0.013000000000000789 seconds
zebra: 0.33999999999999986 seconds
browse: 4.137 seconds
fast_mu: 0.0070000000000014495 seconds
nand: 0.1280000000000001 seconds
perfect: 0.07199999999999918 seconds
yes
```

For GNU Prolog 1.4.5, I use the sample embedding script in `logtalk3/scripts/embedding/gprolog` to create an executable that includes the `bench` example fully compiled:

```
| ?- run.
boyer: 9.3459999999999983 seconds
chat_parser: 1.9610000000000003 seconds
crypt: 0.048000000000000043 seconds
derive: 0.0020000000000006679 seconds
divide10: 0.00099999999999944578 seconds
log10: 0.00099999999999944578 seconds
meta_qsort: 0.099000000000000199 seconds
mu: 0.012999999999999901 seconds
nreverse: 0.0060000000000002274 seconds
ops8: 0.00099999999999944578 seconds
poly_10: 0.72000000000000064 seconds
prover: 0.016000000000000014 seconds
qsort: 0.0080000000000008953 seconds
queens_8: 0.68599999999999994 seconds
query: 0.041999999999999815 seconds
reducer: 0.0 seconds
sendmore: 1.1070000000000011 seconds
serialise: 0.0060000000000002274 seconds
simple_analyzer: 0.25 seconds
tak: 1.3899999999999988 seconds
times10: 0.0010000000000012221 seconds
unify: 0.089999999999999858 seconds
zebra: 0.63499999999999979 seconds
browse: 10.923999999999999 seconds
fast_mu: 0.015000000000000568 seconds

(27352 ms) yes
```

I suggest you try these benchmarks, running them on your computer, with the Prolog systems that you want to compare. In doing that, remember that this is a limited set of benchmarks, not necessarily reflecting the actual relative performance in non-trivial applications.

---

Ratios:

```
              SICStus/SWI   GNU/SWI

boyer               17.4%     44.7%
browse              13.3%     35.2%
chat_parser          9.6%     24.6%
crypt               19.8%     32.8%
derive              22.4%     44.8%
divide10            43.5%     43.5%
fast_mu             17.1%     36.6%
flatten                 -         -
log10               87.0%     87.0%
meta_qsort           9.2%     36.3%
mu                  11.0%     28.7%
nand                13.3%         -
nreverse            11.8%     35.4%
ops8                61.6%     61.6%
perfect             19.6%         -
poly_10             10.5%     36.8%
prover              11.4%     30.3%
qsort                9.7%     25.9%
queens_8            11.5%     30.8%
query               21.4%     36.0%
reducer            226.2%      0.0%
sendmore            19.9%     36.3%
serialise          530.5%   1591.5%
simple_analyzer     11.0%     29.7%
tak                 10.7%     25.3%
times10             52.2%     52.2%
unify               11.6%     80.1%
zebra               21.3%     39.8%
```

P.S. Be sure to use Logtalk 3.43.0 or later as it includes portability fixes for the `bench` example, including for GNU Prolog, and a set of basic unit tests.

Comment: I edited in the ratios. I hope you don't mind. `reducer` seems suspicious

Answer (score 5):

I have some benchmark results published at:

https://logtalk.org/performance.html

Be sure to read and understand the notes at the end of that page, however.

Regarding running benchmarks with GNU Prolog, note that you cannot use the top-level interpreter as code loaded from it is interpreted, not compiled (see GNU Prolog documentation on `gplc`). In general, is not uncommon to see people running benchmarks from the top-level interpreter, forgetting what the word *interpreter* means, and publishing bogus stats where compilation/term-expansion/... steps mistakenly end up mixed with what's supposed to be benchmarked.

Comment: SICStus / SWI ≈ 6, for static code, similar to the old benchmark?

Comment: @MaxB See my alternative answer.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this comparison from 2008 in the Internet archive:

https://web.archive.org/web/20100227050426/http://www.probp.com/performance.htm

[image]

Comment: @PauloMoura Another danger of "classical benchmarks" (in any community) is that compiler writers optimize specifically for them.

Comment: Somehow vaguely remember this comparison. In particular, GNU Prolog is only used in its interpreter version. Not the compiler version.