# Identifying recursive/nested types in Haskell (like type synonyms)

Tags: haskell, recursion, types, type-synonyms

### Short Question (edited):

Is it possible to define a function's type signature so that it accepts nested types with arbitrary depth? I am looking for the behaviour of type synonyms (NOT newtype) but identifying nested/recursive types.

For example a function defined as `f :: NestedList a -> b` should be able to be called with `[a]`, `[[a]]`, `[[[a]]]`... and so on.

### Long Question (original):

Since it is impossible to use type synonyms in Haskell with recursive types, is there a solution for the following problem?

I need a synonym like `NestedList a` that would identify `[a]`, `[[a]]`, `[[[a]]]`... and so on, in function type definitions. An example of function needed to be implemented is:

```
   flatten :: NestedList a -> [a]
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994051/is-there-a-function-to-flatten-a-nested-list-of-elements) shows a solution for `flatten` using the MultiParamTypeClasses language extension, but it does not particularly solve my problem. I need to define functions outside of a class.

**EDIT:**

`flatten` is just an example for a function definition, I am not interested in the function as such. I need a mechanism to define a function with `NestedList a` and call it with a parameter like `[[a]]` or `[[[a]]]`, without the need of an additional type constructor, get methods, etc. As suggested in the title, I need something that behaves like a type synonym on nested lists, mainly for giving type signatures for functions that work on `[...[a]...]` while making sure the base type is `a`.

According to Haskell's strong-typed system this is impossible and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963376/why-dont-type-synonyms-permit-recursion-in-haskell) sheds some light on the reasons why. I am just asking if there is a macro/synonym like mechanism or workaround, or a language extension that permits me to do that.

Answer (score 6):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
data NestedList a = List [NestedList a] | Element a

flatten :: NestedList a -> [a]
flatten (Element x) = [x]
flatten (List xs)   = concatMap flatten xs
```

#### EDIT

As user2407038 has suggested, if you are interested in using the `Foldable` (include `{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}` at the top of your file and `import Data.Foldable`) GHC extension, you can just do this

```
data NestedList a = List [NestedList a] | Element a deriving (Foldable)
```

And then there is a function called `toList` already defined in `Foldable` which will produce the same output as `flatten` from above.

#### EDIT 2

Here is something else of interest concerning the updated question. Ideally, it would be nice to be able to define an instance of `Foldable` with

```
instance (Foldable t, Functor t, Foldable t') => Foldable (t . t')
```

where `(t . t') a` is a type synonym for `t (t' a)` (a sort of type level composition). This obviously doesn't work, and I'm inclined to think there is a logical explanation as to why introducing this would break Haskell in some fundamental way, but I can't think of it. However, there is a package called [Control.Compose](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/TypeCompose-0.6.7/docs/Control-Compose.html) which defines something almost like that (except for the fact we would like a `type` synonym as opposed to a `newtype`).

```
newtype (g :. f) a = O { unO :: g (f a) }
```

This lets us write the following:

```
toList $ (O) [[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6]]
toList $ (O . O) [[[1],[2,3,4]],[[4],[5,6]]]
toList $ (O . O . O) [[[[1]],[[2,3],[4]]],[[[4]],[[5,6]]]]
```

Which is also of interest.

Comment: Or just `data NestedList a = List [NestedList a] | Element a deriving Foldable`.

Comment: Indeed, your solution does work with `flatten`, but this is not what I am trying to achieve. I guess I was not very specific, and I will edit my question. The problem is that I cannot use `[[[Int]]]` and `NestedList Int` interchangeably, i.e. call the function with `[[[Int]]]`. This is why I would like something that works like type synonyms.

Comment: @GeorgeUngureanu I see. I don't think you will find type synonym `Datalist a` that will work for `[a]`, `[[a]]`, etc. since that would mean that `[a] = Datalist a = [[a]]` yet this is clearly untrue.

Comment: @Alec: Absolutely! And Haskell does not permit that, indeed. But a function implemented in an applicative manner works perfectly with `[a]`, `[[a]]`, etc. I just need to give that function a type signature (while still making sure that the base type is `a`)